# Efficient multiselection algorithm

Tags: algorithm

I have to implement an algorithm that solves the multi-selection problem.
The multiselection problem is:

> Given a set S of n elements drawn from a linearly ordered set, and a set K = {k1, k2,...,kr} of positive integers between 1 and n, the multiselection problem is to select the ki-th smallest element for all values of i, 1 <= i <= r

I need to solve the average case on Θ(n log r)
I've found a paper that implements the solution I need, but it assumes that there are no repeated numbers on the set S. The problem is that I can't assume that and I don't know how to adapt the algorithm of that paper to support repeated numbers.
The paper is here: http://www.ccse.kfupm.edu.sa/~suwaiyel/publications/multiselection_parCom.pdf 
and the algorithm is on the second page. Any tips are welcome!

Comment: Why can't you simply sort the set using quicksort and choose the kith elements directly? Not sure if I understand correctly.

Comment: @AbhishekBansal because its cost would be Θ(n log n) on the average which is higher than what I'm asked for

Comment: I have an implementation of this algorithm at https://github.com/jmlundberg/nth_element_material/tree/main/code .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For posterity: the algorithm to which Ivan refers is to sort K, then solve the problem recursively as follows. Use QuickSelect to find the ki-th smallest element x where i is ceil(r/2), then recurse on the smaller halves of K and S, and the larger halves of K and S, splitting K about i and S about x.

Finding algorithms that work in the presence of degeneracy (here, equal elements) is often not a high priority for authors of theoretical works, because it makes the presentation of the common case more difficult and doesn't often play a role in determining the computational complexity of the problem. This is essentially a one-dimensional problem, and the black box solution is easy; replace the i-th element of the input yi by (yi, i) and break ties in the comparisons using the second component.

In practice, we can do better. Instead of recursing on {y : y in S, y < x} and {y : y in S, y > x}, use a three-way partitioning algorithm about x (see, e.g., every sufficiently complete treatment of QuickSort), then divide the array S by index instead of value.

Comment: Thanks, replacing yi by (yi, i) and using the indexes on comparison worked like a charm